# JavaScript regExp returns "null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, function, methods

I'm making a regular expression to match for all the `li` in 1  `ul` in 1 `textarea`.  Everytime I click the button, it returns a value of `null`.

**Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/1/).**

Here's what my `function(){...}` looks like:

```
function doIt() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var patt = /^<ol>{1}\n+\s?[<li>\w+<\/li>]+\n+<\/ol>{1}$/;
    alert(input.value.match(patt));
}
```

I really don't know why `patt` doesn't work...

Here's the logic (in my own words):

- `^` — Starting point
- `<ol>{1}` — Look for 1 `<ol>`
- `\n+` — Look for 1 or more new lines
- `\s?` — Look for 0 or more (optional) spaces
- `[<li>\w+<\/li>]+` — Look for 1 or more `<li></li>` that contains 1 or more characters.
- `\n+` — Look for 1 or more new lines
- `<\/ol>{1}` — Look for 1 `</ol>`
- `$` — Ending point

---

- I want `[<li>\w+<\/li>]+` to return 1 or more of something like: `<li>Hello world :)</li>`

Basically, ANYTHING can be in between `<li></li>`.

Comment: regExp doesn't return `null`, `match` does as there are no matches

Comment: @user2864740 [This](http://www.regexr.com/) is free

Comment: Then use it - build up the regular expression slowly. When one part doesn't work, analyze is separately.

Comment: Note: JavaScript regular expressions return the matches obtained, not the results of grouping operators, so if you want to obtain "1 or more of something like `<li>...</li>`" then the surrounding `<ol>` etc. cannot be part of your regular expression. (If you are wanting to obtain one or more entire parent ordered list elements as matches, then you are taking the correct approach.)

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing an HTML string with RegEx especially if you're already in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your pattern actually does:

```
^                — Maches the beginning of the string
<ol              — Matches "<ol"
>{1}             — matches ">" one time
\n+              — Matches 1 or more new lines
\s?              — Matches 1 whitespace character (optional)
[<li>\w+<\/li>]+ — Matches any of the characters in "<>A-Za-z_/" 1 or more times
\n+              — Matches 1 or more new lines
<\/ol            — Matches "</ol"
>{1}             — Matches ">" one time
$                — Matches the end of the string
```

As you match the beginning and the end of the string, the pattern would have to match the entire string, not part of the string.

If you put only this in the textarea, the pattern will match it:

```
<ol>
<li>Helloworld</li><li>Hellohowareyou</li><li>good</li>
</ol>
```

You would rather want something like this:

```
var patt = /<ol>\s*(?:<li>[\w !:)]+<\/li>\s*)+<\/ol>/;
```

Explanation:

```
<ol>             — Matches "<ol>"
\s*              — Matches zero or more whitespace characters (including newlines)
(?:              — Starts a non-capturing group
<li>             — Matches "<li>"
[\w+ !:)]+       — Matches any of the characters in "A-Za-z_ !:)" 1 or more times
<\/li>           — Matches "</li>"
\s*              — Matches zero or more whitespace characters
)                — Ends the group
+                — Repeats the group one or more times
\n+              — Matches 1 or more new lines
<\/ol>           — Matches "</ol>"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/2/

Comment: Thank you, It works nicely! Is there a way to match any character, instead of limiting it to `A-Za-z_ !:)`?  I tried `.*` but it returned null.

Comment: Ahh, I figured it out!  Replaced `[\w+ !:)]+ ` with `.+`

Answer (score 1):

The square bracket mean match any single character between the brackets.

You want to pull the `<li>` and the `</li>` outside the brackets - something like `\<li\>.*\<\\li\>`.

Comment: (The OP wants to use grouping parens, and eliminate the square brackets entirely, so it will match "one or more" LI groups.)

Comment: @Upperstate Ohh, okay.  Any idea why it's alerting null?  Possibly because the expression is incorrect, right?  I understand that `.*` means one or more of any character, but why all the slashes?

Comment: You might be right - maybe all the slashes are not necessary. I will fiddle and then update the answer.